# Azure Storage Emulator did not upgrade when I updated SDK

Tags: azure-storage, azure-compute-emulator

I upgraded the Azure SDK to 2.9.6 earlier today as the setup completed without any error messages which lead me to believe it completed successfully. However, I'm noticing that the storage emulator is still version 4.5 (I expected it to be upgraded to 4.6).

I ran the Web Platform Installer again but it says the latest SDK is already installed and nothing needs to be upgraded.

Is there a way to force the storage emulator to be upgraded (other than uninstalling the whole SDK and reinstalling)?

***Update:***
I uninstalled the emulator 4.5, ran the Web Installer Platform again and it detected the missing emulator, I completed the install but to my surprise, it installed version 4.5 again!!! What do I need to do to install emulator 4.6?

By the way, the reason why I want emulator 4.6 is because I have upgraded my C# solution to use the Azure Storage nuget package version 8.0.0 which requires the latest emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind: I found a link to [download the emulator](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=717179&clcid=0x409).

Comment: Saved me hours of head-scratching +1